# why run this command :"gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye"

Tags: gnupg, archlinux, gpg-agent

I have a arch linux in vm,
I imported my gpg keys and configs gpg as described here:

https://github.com/drduh/YubiKey-Guide

and also config pass & git to use gpg keys, and everything works fine,
so for example when I run `git pull` for first time it asks me the password,

the problem is:
when I restart my vm, before I can run any command(like `git pull`),I have to run this command:

```
gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
```

then everything works fine,

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

GPG depends on `pinentry` to provide user interaction for typing the passwords such as the one to protect your smartcard. In order to function properly, `pinentry` (which, on terminal, is either `pinentry-tty` or `pinentry-curses`) needs to know which tty it should listen for user interaction.

When GPG is acting as your `ssh-agent` to provide git+ssh authentication, it will keep a reference of the first `tty` available when it started, which is not the same you will have when you connect to your VM. Unfortunately, `gpg-agent` has no way to know at runtime which `tty` you are connected to, so it will fail every time it tries to communicate with its startup `tty`. That's why you need to update the startup tty using that command. This behavior is shortly described [on their docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-UPDATESTARTUPTTY.html).

An alternative to avoid that command every time is to use any `pinentry` application that does not rely on `tty`, such as GUI ones like `pinentry-gtk-2`, `pinentry-gnome` and so on.